# Forward data from ip socket to bluetooth socket. c#

Tags: c#, java, sockets, bluetooth

I want to listen to incoming ip sockets on a specific port and forward them using bluetooth sockets. 
Is this possible?

I'm using c# but I can use java if it's easier to code.

Comment: Could you please give me hints from where to start...

Comment: Well for start you might whant to google "c# sockets tutorial" or smth of the sort, after youre comfortable with reading sockets on a specific port you can try to google "c# bluetooth tutorial" and that should give you relevant tutorials on how to establish a bluetooth connection and send/recive data .

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the object was using SMB protocol over Bluetooth connexion. I found a Bluetooth profile that is similar to SMB protocol and that enables me to explore the sdcard from my PC. the profile is OBEX FTP (File Transfert Profile) and i found java APIs.
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth equivalent of TCP sockets are called RFCOMM sockets.  You can write an app to open a TCP socket, read the data, and write it out to an RFCOMM socket.